Error "Missing } inserted." when trying to use calendar.sty
I want to create monthly calendars for an arbitrary year using LaTeX, each month would be shown on a separate page and there should be a blank space for each day so that I can handwrite on that blank space, the dimensions for all days should be the same. The calendar for each month should use as much space in the page as possible. The image below shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

* Image above retrieved from https://github.com/jhordyess/calendar-generator
I found this Github repository which uses this template and it uses Python for generating the calendar for each month of the year. That template and that Python code pretty much suit my use case.
I cloned the Github repository using the command below.
rm -rf /tmp/calendar-generator \
  && git clone 'https://github.com/jhordyess/calendar-generator' /tmp/calendar-generator

For the record (for future readers of this question), this is the specific commit from that Github repository that I was using:
$ cd /tmp/calendar-generator && git log -n 1
commit f1f16c49fc0d6819866c40d15dcbf9e222b11abe (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: jhordyess <dev@jhordyess.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 27 23:15:27 2023 +0000

    Add CSV data and update calendar generation logic

I tried compiling the document by first running the Python script (which generates index.tex) and then compiling index.tex using pdflatex as shown below:
python3 index.py
pdflatex index.tex

The python3 command doesn't throw errors, but the pdflatex throws some errors. The errors are shown in the code block below. I have omitted some lines because they were too many, you can read the complete logs at https://archive.ph/YnHyd
$ cd /tmp/calendar-generator && bash run.sh
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./index.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./calendar.sty
'calendar' style 3.22018/09/19.
Created by Evan Sultanik
****** Bugs/comments/suggestions/technicalities to Evan Sultanik -- evan@sultan
ik.com ******
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file index.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
./index.tex:44: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.44 \end{calendar}

./index.tex:44: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<inserted text> }

(... omitted lines ...)

l.44 \end{calendar}

./index.tex:44: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<inserted text> }

l.44 \end{calendar}

(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
./index.tex:44:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on index.log.
/tmp/calendar-generator

I tried debugging the file index.tex and I was able to get the same error with the minimal example below.
\documentclass[landscape,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{calendar}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{calendar}{.97\textwidth}
  \BlankDay\BlankDay\BlankDay\setcounter{calendardate}{1}
  \day{}{\vspace{2cm}}
  \day{}{\vspace{2cm}}
  \BlankDay\BlankDay\BlankDay\finishCalendar
\end{calendar}
\end{document}

$ pdflatex index.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./index.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./calendar.sty
'calendar' style 3.22018/09/19.
Created by Evan Sultanik
****** Bugs/comments/suggestions/technicalities to Evan Sultanik -- evan@sultan
ik.com ******
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./index.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.12 \end{calendar}

? 


Additional notes
Note 1: I recall I was able to compile index.tex from that Github repository approximately 8 months ago. At that time, I was using a different computer with perhaps another TeXLive version, so I suspect that one reason why that document can't be compiled is that the new TeXLive version introduced some changes that broke calendar.sty. This is the version that I'm using:
pdflatex --version

pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.43; using libpng 1.6.43
Compiled with zlib 1.3.1; using zlib 1.3.1
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04

Note 2: I'm open to other ways  for creating a monthly calendar with the characteristics that I described above. That is, I am not constrained to using the code in that particular Github repository, if you are aware of other LaTeX packages that can get the same result, I'd appreciate you could share them with me.

it looks as if there is a clash with the newest array.sty. I would recommend to look for another calendar, the code doesn't look good.

I'd adapt A653146 to your needs. PGFCalendar in combination with TikZ is very powerful and might just be easier to use.

I'm answering my own question: I mentioned that I was open to suggestions of other packages, so I ended up modifying the code from the answer that @Qrrbrbirlbel mentioned in his/her comment.

\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}\cfoot{}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{ext.calendar-plus}
\tikzset{
  % just some dummy defaults
  height for calendar/.initial=\textheight,
  weeks in this month/.initial=6,
  %
  wall calendar/.style={
    week list, day text=, % empty day nodes
    day xshift=\linewidth/7,
    day yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/height for calendar}/
               \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/weeks in this month},
    %
    % recalculates the number of weeks per month at the first of the month
    % uses expandable shorthand \%m- (provided by tikz-ext)
    % to drop preceding 0 for PGFMath
    execute before day scope=
      \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
        \pgfmathweeksinmonthofyear{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}{\%m-}{\%y-}%
        \tikzset{weeks in this month/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}}{},
    every weekday/.style={
      draw=black, outer sep=+0pt, anchor=north west,
      fill=blue!10!white, text=black,
      minimum width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/day xshift},% \tikz@lib@cal@xshift
      font=\strut,
      xshift=##1*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/day xshift}),%  \tikz@lib@cal@xshift
      name=weekday-##1,
      node contents=\pgfcalendarweekdayname{##1},
      weekday-##1/.try},
    every head/.style={
      name=cal@head,
      anchor=north west,
      align=left},
    every day/.append style={
      draw=black, outer sep=+0pt, anchor=north west,
      label={[every day label]north west:},
      minimum width=\linewidth/7,
      minimum height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/day yshift}},% \tikz@lib@cal@yshift
    every day label/.style={
      anchor=north west,
      font=\scriptsize,
      node contents={\%d-}}}
}
\makeatletter % quick low-level versions instead of calc library
\newcommand*\getHeightOfHeader{%
  \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{cal@head}{south}}
               {\pgfpointanchor{cal@head}{north}}%
  \pgfgetlastxy\tikz@temp\tikz@headheight
  \pgftransformyshift{-\tikz@headheight}}
\newcommand*\getHeightOfWeekdays{%
  \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{weekday-0}{south}}
               {\pgfpointanchor{weekday-0}{north}}%
  \pgfgetlastxy\tikz@temp\tikz@weekdayheight
  \pgftransformyshift{-\tikz@weekdayheight}
  \pgfmathadd@{\tikz@headheight}{\tikz@weekdayheight}%
  \pgfmathsubtract@{\textheight}{\pgfmathresult}
  \tikzset{height for calendar/.expanded=\pgfmathresult pt}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\Year{2025}
\begin{document}\sffamily
\foreach \mon in {1,...,12}{%
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  wall calendar, trim left=(weekday-0.west),trim right=(weekday-6.east)
]
%
%% Headers
\node[every head]
     {\strut\Year-\ifnum\mon<10 0\fi\mon\hspace{5pt}\pgfcalendarmonthname{\mon}};
\getHeightOfHeader
%
%% Weekdays
\foreach \weekday in {0,...,6}
  \node[every weekday=\weekday];
\getHeightOfWeekdays
%
%% The calendar itself
\calendar[dates=\Year-\mon-01 to \Year-\mon-last];
\end{tikzpicture}\par\pagebreak}
\end{document}


I could compile that document above using the following pdflatex version:
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.43; using libpng 1.6.43
Compiled with zlib 1.3.1; using zlib 1.3.1
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04

